# Opentk: Move Bones model 3d

Tags: opengl

I have a model in 3ds max and have exported to obj file using tutorials and I managed to load my model and apply a texture. My problem is that I have to move a part of this model and to move while their children. I've done things with XNA and it was very easy to do but not how to export opengl inheritance from my file 3ds max .. You have any idea how I can do this or any tutorials that can help me. thanks

Comment: Can you be more specific with the part of the process you're having  trouble with? Answering your question now would likely give you an answer that's too broad to be  useful to you. Please edit your question with more detail. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, I don't know how load the skeleton of my model, I don't know export form 3ds Max. In XNA I used fbx file what content bones and hierarchy and it weas very esasy. How I can to do in OpenGL? What files need?

Comment: Still a bit too broad. What have you tried already? What about it isn't working? Search the site for similar questions, like: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18487/animation-in-opengl-using-3d-models?rq=1.

Answer (score 1):

**File Formats** - OBJ does not support bones. You have to chose a file format that does, such as FBX or MD5.

**Loading Models in OpenGL** - In terms of drawing graphics, OpenGL (and OpenTK) is little more than a low-level "Give-triangle-buffers-to-graphics-card" library, and has no concept of "models", "bones", or "animation". You could use model import libraries (such as AssImp) or more fully featured game engines (MonoGame, OGRE, Irrlicht, etc) to get this functionality, or you will have to code your own classes for them.

Comment: Hello, forgive my limited explanations. I am new to OpenGL. Let's see if I can explain well, what I have achieved so far is to load my model exported to a file obj My problem is that I want to move an arm of my model and simultaneously move the wrist and hand. Could you do it loading my model from obj file (which is what I got) and create me a file containing the relationship between parents and children and their possible moves? Any examples you may know? Thanks